# How did the Veil open (and close)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022

In Episode 5 of *Ms. Marvel*, the Veil separating the human world from the Noor Dimension suddenly opens for no apparent reason. One of the Clandestines tries to go through it and is gruesomely disintegrated.

Kamala manages to convince Najma not to try going through the Veil, and

> Najma suddenly declares that she can close the Veil, which she *somehow* manages to do, despite it disintegrating her in the exact same way.

None of this is explained, nor does it make any sense to me.

**How did the Veil open in the first place, and how was this character able to close it?**

Comment: "None of this is explained" — which is understandable in-universe. The two people who explained the Noor dimension to Kamala (Najma and Waleed) are apparently dead, so unless Kareem was extensively briefed on its workings, no-one knows what's up with it. Presumably we'll learn a bit more in the final episode, although maybe we'll need to watch _The Marvels_ (or even _Thor: Love and Thunder_?) to get the picture.

Comment: Well, it makes quite a bit of sense to me, but I think it's better to wait for last episode.

Comment: @Mithoron I've just finished watching the final episode and, beyond a vague mention of Najma "pierc[ing] the Veil", no further explanation is given. If it made sense to you, would you consider posting an answer?

Comment: Maybe. This last episode indeed didn't explain much, we only got Kamala's interpretation. It would be pretty speculative, but I could give it a shot.

Comment: Note that it all connects with your next question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265515/how-did-kamran-gain-his-powers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Kamala's bangle has the ability to open jump points to other dimensions.

We learn later in *The Marvels* (2023 film) that Kamala's bangle is one of two Quantum Bands, ancient artifacts that have the ability to absorb energy and create jump points through space and even timelines/universes.

In *The Marvels*, the antagonist Dar-Benn obtained the other Quantum Band and used it, by overloading it with the energy from her universal weapon (a Kree Accuser warhammer), to create jump points within the universe.

[image: The Marvels screenshot - Dar-Benn opening a jump point][image: The Marvels screenshot - Dar-Benn opening a jump point][image: The Marvels screenshot - Dar-Benn opening a jump point]

Later in the film, she takes Kamala’s bangle and uses both Quantum Bands, which results in the creation of a jump point to another universe, but this backfires, and the energy released kills her. In *Ms. Marvel* Season 1, Episode 4, Najma triggered Kamala’s bangle when she struck it with her weapon, which opened a jump point to the Noor Dimension.

[image: Ms. Marvel episode 4 screenshot - Najma triggered Kamala’s bangle when she struck it with her weapon]

> **When Najma stabs the bangle, it emits a burst of energy** that transports Kamala Khan back to that pivotal moment in her family history from 1947 when her grandmother, Sana, and great-grandparents were boarding the train to Pakistan.

<sup>- *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*, page 315 (emphasis mine)</sup>

In *The Marvels*, Monica Rambeau explains that the only way to close a jump point created by the Quantum Bands is to release the same amount of energy into it that was used to open it. (In a [deleted scene](https://twitter.com/USATODAY/status/1744359288259154194), this information was relayed to Monica by Talia, a S.A.B.E.R. agent who analyzed the jump points created by the Quantum Bands.) Monica managed to close the jump point to another universe by absorbing the energy from Ms. Marvel (who used the two Quantum Bands) and Captain Marvel, and then releasing it to the jump point.

Najma does the same thing in *Ms. Marvel* to close the Veil. She sacrifices herself, releasing her energy into the Veil as she dies, which closes it. We see this happen in Season 1, Episode 5.

[image: screenshot of scene described above][image: screenshot of scene described above][image: screenshot of scene described above]

> When Kamala Khan returns to the present, she sees a column of energy that leads to the Noor Dimension. The Clandestine member Fariha believes she can enter it and return home, but touching the light only disintegrates her. Realizing that Waleed was right, and the tear in dimensions will only grow out of control and destroy the world, **Najma sacrifices her own life to force its closure**, transmitting her powers to her son Kamran, whom she had abandoned back in the United States.

<sup>- *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*, page 316 (emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Great to finally have this explained after so long!

Answer (score 5):

OK, that's gonna be rather speculative, but the series kinda *is* rather enigmatic. Also, this is all like one big *spoiler*.

Lets start with "why did it open?". It was probably because of power output needed to send Kamala into the past.

Looks like there was an interplay between Aisha, Kamala and Najima. Aisha was trying to get help from a future user of the bangle. That caused Kamala's visions of the past, but didn't quite work out. Still, as Najima touched it, the vision not only came back, but even Kamala's grandma saw it. Seems this was a dance for *three* (or maybe even four...) - just after Najima stabbed the bangle, Kamala was finally sent back to past. This made a hole in our reality and apparently also in the veil.

Now, what about closing it?

It's hard to say what Najima could do and how. Like other jinn she had some connection to the Noor. Now this breach was a very big connection that she apparently could manipulate. So, what happened when she touched it? Her body was destroyed, but she managed to manipulate the breach and even influence Kamran at a distance. But what about "dying"? While perhaps she died, in a way, I think it was rather her succeeding in going back to Noor, leaving remains behind, while spirit, or actual "jinn" part, left where she wanted to go.