# How did Kamran gain his powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022

In the penultimate episode of *Ms. Marvel*, Najma imbues Kamran with powers almost identical to Kamala's,

> right before Najma dies.

I don't understand how Najma could bestow these powers when she herself never had them to begin with. Certainly, I don't recall any instances of her, or the other Clandestines, harnessing Noor energy in the same way that Kamala does. Even if we assume that

> Kamran is a mutant, the same way Kamala is implied to be,

that wouldn't explain how Najma was able to unlock his abilities in the first place.

What did Najma do to Kamran that granted him his powers?

Comment: Is it not implied she absorbed the piercing in the Veil (thus closing it) and then somehow transferred that absorbed energy to Kamran? They certainly don't explain it though but I think that's what they were going for.

Comment: If that was implied, it was subtle enough for me not to pick up on it.

Comment: I'm using implied very loosely, that's my interpretation of what is shown but so little is shown that I'm not confident I'm correct. Also why I'm not making it an answer.

Comment: I was wondering if it was somehow related to how Aisha summoned Kamala to the past. In both cases a dying Djinn said the name of someone they love and performed a "wish" of some sort. I don't know if Djinn abilities are ever referenced in the comics.